# Error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing - <nil>

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to bring up the network by './byfn.sh -m up' but getting this error 'Error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing - ' under 'Querying on peer1.org2 on channel 'mychannel'..' . So can I get some help here for hyperledger-fabric?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all docker images:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

Try again,
if problem persists

Download fabric-samples repo again from gitHub
and update docker images via terminal by running this command

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

If still problem persists
watch video by ernesto  where he does all these from SCRATCH!!

here is the link to that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcOUVI9m7qA

kudos